# Bootstrap: Creating 3 input form fields on a row and spacing evenly, taking up half the page's width?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="inline-form">
          <div class="inline-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
          </div>
          <div class="inline-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email address">
          </div>
          <div class="inline-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

I need to create 3 form fields with identical width evenly spaced with each other on a row. The HTML above is inside a div which has .col-md-6 (which should have take up half the page's width).

Comment: I think you forgot to include the `col-md-6` class in your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

I changed:

- form class, from "inline-form" to "form-inline"
- div class, from "inline-form" to "form-control"

My code was based on BS4 help: [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#inline-forms)

if you want to add .col-md-6, your could add before container tag as a DIV tag, like this

```
<div class="cold-md-6">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <form class="form-inline">

                <div class="form-control">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[EDIT]
Based on your own code, I modified yours to reach the result you want.

Some changes:

- form involve all input fields
- delete container in form tag (not a good idea to nest containers)
- add col-4 to each form component
- add col-12 to textarea

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. However I'm still having the problem of them not properly spacing when they are in the half-page column. Can you have a look through the result after I inserted your codes into my webpage? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sXcDu592WIUHLAcU1FiwqqstTvlng5Tj?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the form class to "d-flex flex-row"

or you can wrap the inputs you want on the same line with another div like so

```
<div class="container d-flex mx-auto">
      <div class=" row">
        <form class="form-group">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-4">
            <div class="form-control mr-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control mr-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control mr-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>
          </div>
          <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
```